# Magento PDF Print out Totals Sort order

Tags: magento2, pdf, sort

[image: PDF Sort Order Totals]

Is it possible to change the sort order of the totals in the PDF Print outs?

I would like to have the "Minimum Order Bedrag" under "Subtotaal".
I did manage to change it for the checkout page since there is a nice configuration in the backend. However this is not available for te PDF Print outs.

Comment: first: what is bedrag? second: where in admin do you set sort order for checkout page?

Comment: @LucaS bedrag is dutch for amount. And in the Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales -> Checkout Totals Sort Order you can change the total order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pdf Totals do not have a nice User Interface to change how they are sorted. The sort_order is determined by the `etc/pdf.xml` files. For example in /vendor/magento/module-sales/etc/pdf.xml you'll find

```
    <total name="subtotal">
        <title translate="true">Subtotal</title>
        <source_field>subtotal</source_field>
        <font_size>7</font_size>
        <display_zero>true</display_zero>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
    </total>
    <total name="discount">
        <title translate="true">Discount</title>
        <source_field>discount_amount</source_field>
        <title_source_field>discount_description</title_source_field>
        <font_size>7</font_size>
        <display_zero>false</display_zero>
        <sort_order>200</sort_order>
    </total>
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to that file! I will look into it and probably will figure out how it works!